# How to close Scaffold's drawer after an item tap?

Tags: dart, flutter

After I tap an item in the Scaffold's drawer I want it to automatically hide itself. How do I do it in Flutter?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Navigator.pop()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) will pop the `Drawer` route off the stack and cause it to close.

Comment: But this means I need to add this call to every onTap handler, right?

Comment: Yeah. You could refactor the call to `pop` into a shared private method if the code duplication bothers you.

Comment: So, if I want open a new route at the same time, I have to close the drawer first and then push another. the drawer works a really dumb way. LOL. I have thought the drawer as a widget of scaffold, but it seems that I'm definitely wrong. :(

Comment: I am sorry, but `Navigator.pop()` does not close the drawer in my case... (neither do  `Navigator.pop(context)` or  `Navigator.pop(context, true)` do so.... What do I need to do in order to close the drawer by selecting one of its items ?  My Drawer is inside a Scaffold inside a MaterialApp... does this matter maybe ??

Comment: It seems that the MaterialApp indeed caused a problem (since the context was missing). I found a solution [from this link...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49374128/3826232)

Answer (score 47):

First create a ScaffoldState key

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,)
```

Now you can open and close the drawer using the `toggleDrawer()` method.

for the left drawer

```
toggleDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  } else {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  }
}
```

for the right drawer

```
toggleDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  } else {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  }
}
```

Comment: i feel this is the best answer to programaticaly manage the drawer

Comment: How does this close drawer?

Comment: Great solution but it should be noted that this does not work for the drawer if it is placed on the "right" side. `Scaffold(endDrawer: Drawer())`

Comment: @Matthew for endDrawer

  toggleDrawer() async {
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
    } else {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
    }
  }

Comment: for right side drawer    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isEndDrawerOpen) {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                } else {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
                }

Comment: Doesn't work with pushing named routes as it say's the key is being used multiple times.

Answer (score 38):

`Navigator.of(context).pop()` should do what you want :)

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html

Answer (score 35):

Shorthand for closing the drawer and navigating to a new route:

`Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/newroute');`

Answer (score 21):

If you simply want to close the `Drawer`, you can use any of the following:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

---

And if you want to navigate to a new page, you can use

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/new_page");
```

or

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()));
```

Comment: How to name a page?

Answer (score 6):

For the lastest Flutter version (v0.3.2 when I am writing this), the implementation changed a bit and `Navigator.pop()` now requires a given context.

[Navigator.pop(context)](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) is the typical usage for closing a route.
[Navigator.pop(context, **true**)](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) is the usage for closing a route with a returned result.

See [Drawer Class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html) and [example](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/) on Flutter's Cookbook.

Answer (score 6):

This is the answer

**First in Class**

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

**Second In Widget**

```
 Scaffold(key: _scaffoldKey,)
```

**Third in code**

```
if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what the OP is possibly trying to say is that even though Navigator.of(context).pop() and Navigator.pop(context) should work, they aren't in his case- I'm having the same issue.

Early on in a project the drawer works as it should - opening and closing properly. Since several changes have been made (none directly to the drawer or its scaffold) the drawer is no longer closing with Navigator.of(context).pop() and Navigator.pop(context).

I did a little more digging and found that instead of using Navigator.pop you can use Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer to close the drawer - even though it doesn't seem like it should. I've never used this function until now but it works perfectly. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: ```Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer``` will open the end drawer so while opening the enddrawer, it probably closes the current drawer,it will get your work done but its not the right way to do that,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code according to your requirement.

When you want to remove and push new route:

```
Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/routeName');
```

When you want to just pop:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

First Pop widget, after that Push your route it will automatically close the Drawer when you come back next time.

```
Navigator.pop(context); // Widget will be poped
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/routename'); // New Route will be pushed
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its quite Easy

**Problem Statement** : In default Home Page when someone presses back button , (if drawer is open) it is closed, else a prompt is thrown asking for Exit Application "Yes" and "No".

**Solution**

1. Add

   GlobalKey _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();
2. Make Function **Future _onWillPop() async** handling the required problem statement
3. Call key and onWillPop as given in the below source code

See Through full source code For the additions done related to this problem statement in source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    if(_scaffoldKey.currentState != null && _scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen){
      return true;
    }
    return (await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Leaving our App?'),
            content: new Text('Are you sure you want to Exit?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )) ??
        false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Welcome My App"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Notification Setting',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0, color: HexColor(HexColor.gray_text)),
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_outlined,
                size: 24.0,
                color: HexColor(HexColor.primarycolor),
              ),
              onTap: () {

                _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openEndDrawer();
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return NotificationSettingActivity();
                }
                ));
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add Navigator.pop to your button or widget you tap

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the Scaffold's drawer after an item tap, you can use the Navigator.pop(context) method. Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Drawer Example'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Do something when the item is tapped
                // Close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Do something when the item is tapped
                // Close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Navigate.of(context).pop();
**OR**
Navigate.pop(contex);

must be the first in onTap() function

for example :

```
 onTap: () {
 Navigator.of(context).pop();//before pushing to any other route 
 Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen2(),
   ),
  );
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your answer.  However, this is really a duplicate, since the accepted answer is already to use Navigator.pop(). It feels like you are trying to answer some of the commenters who said that it didn't work for them, and that would be better done in a comment when you have that privilege.